# Elasticsearch: Ignore / Don't index field if types changes

Tags: elasticsearch

my elasticsearch receives many JSON logs. I have no control about the schema.
Is it possible to dynamically index new fields, but to somehow unindex them if the type of the field has changed?

The reason behind this is, that I do not have a schema of the JSON logs. I also don't want to loose logs because of field type mismatching. Finaly I want to be able to make queries on those fields with a consistent field type!

Many Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: What do you mean "unindex them if the type of the field has changed"? The type of a field cannot be changed.

Comment: Hay, as far as I know I can define fields in my JSON log to not be indexed. If they are not indexed elasticsearch does not allocate a type to the field (correct me if I'm wrong). I can not say which fields will occur in my JSON logs and I can not tell which fields will always have the same type (a priory). So by "unindexing" I mean to somehow find a way to "accept" JSON logs with fields of different types, even if this leads to an unsearchable field (because the indexing is reverted or how ever). This "unindexing" is all under the premiss, that not indexed fields can hold different types.

Comment: No. The story is like this: if a field doesn't exist, it will be created in the mapping. And ES will do its best to "guess" the type of that field. BUT, if you try to index afterwards something that doesn't match the initial type ES will complain. For example, if you indexed a number and ES guessed this it will create an index of `type: long`. Afterwards if you inde x a document with a field with the same name as that `long` field, but you put `"bla bla"` as a value ES will complain and not index your document. If you want to ignore this type of errors you need `ignore_malformed: true`.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html

Comment: Hay, maybe this could be a solution to my problem. The documentation says, that the field with not fitting type will not be indexed. Not indexed means I can not search, but the field exists in the document? So when I have a field called "age" and it's first appearance will be a number. I can make queries with "age" = 50 and elasticsearch will ignore all documents where "age" = "50" (or any other string) ?

Comment: Yes. The value is not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field doesn't exist, it will be created in the mapping by default. And ES will do its best to "guess" the type of that field. BUT, if you try to index afterwards something that doesn't match the initial type ES will complain. For example, if you indexed a number and ES guessed this it will create an index of `type: long`. Afterwards if you index a document with a field with the same name as that `long` field, but you put `"bla bla"` as a value ES will complain and not index your document. If you want to ignore this type of errors you need `ignore_malformed: true`. Relevant documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html):

> Sometimes you don’t have much control over the data that you receive. One user may send a login field that is a date, and another sends a login field that is an email address.
>
> Trying to index the wrong datatype into a field throws an exception by default, and rejects the whole document. The ignore_malformed parameter, if set to true, allows the exception to be ignored. The malformed field is not indexed, but other fields in the document are processed normally.